# How can I create second var automatically?

Tags: python, variables

I parse a text file for the following line.

stp               11441      0          0          0          0

there are always 2 such line occurrences in the txt file. I am looking for the second value in the line (11441 here) and save it as a variable.

I have figured it out how to do such manipulations with only one variable.
Here is the code I am using

```
import re
with open('cpu.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        match = re.search('stp               \d{2,100}', line)
        if match:
            stp_queue1 = match.group().split( )[1]
```

However, I can't get my head around how I specify a variable (`stp_queue2` in that case) for the second time match occurrence.

In other words:
if the file contains 2 following lines:

```
stp 11441 0 0 0 0
stp 20000 0 0 0 0
```

then `stp_queue1` should be 11441 and `stp_queue2` should be 20000 respectively.

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use regex? There may be simpler approaches if all you need is to fetch that first numeric value.

Answer (score 2):

There are many patterns you can use for this problem :

i am showing you three pattern, you can choose which you want :

> first pattern :

```
import re

pattern=r'stp\s(\d+)'

output=[]
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match=re.search(pattern,line)
        output.append(match.group(1))

print(output)
```

output:

```
['11441', '20000']
```

> Pattern 2:

```
r'[0-9]{5}'
```

> pattern 3:

```
Positive Lookbehind (?<=stp\s)

pattern=r'(?<=stp\s)\d+'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add your values to a dictionary rather than each to its own variable.  See the code below for adding each match to a dictionary with the key being stp_queue# with the number starting at 1.

```
import re
dictionary={}
with open('cpu.txt', 'r') as file:
    counter=1
    for line in file:
        match = re.search('stp               \d{2,100}', line)
        if match:
           dictionary["stp_queue"+str(counter)]  = match.group().split( )[1]
           counter++
print dictionary
```

Then to extract the data `dictionary["stp_queue1"]` will return the value stored for the first match found.

More on dictionaries here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: You should go ahead and accept that answer when you get a chance :)

Answer (score 1):

If you put them in a list the order is preserved and look up is as easy as `stp_queue[0]`

```
import re
stp_queue = []
with open('cpu.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        match = re.search('stp               \d{2,100}', line)
        if match:
            stp_queue.append(match.group().split( )[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a list containing the that first number following `stp` this may be enough:

```
with open('cpu.txt', 'r') as f:
    stp_queue = [line.split()[1] for line in f]

print(stp_queue)
```

If you need to check whether the line begins with `stp` just add that validation to the comprehension:

```
with open('cpu.txt', 'r') as f:
    stp_queue = [line.split()[1] for line in f if line.startswith('stp')]

print(stp_queue)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `groups` in your regular expression.
Please read python regex documentation